# How to extend q.promise in node.js?

Tags: node.js, promise

I need to extent q.promise with my own functions, I tried:

```
defer = q.defer();
defer.promise.prototype.funcName = function () {
    // my function
}
```

witch returns following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'funcName' of undefined
```

How should I properly extend `q.promise`?

---

This is my actual problem: I need an alias for `.then()` witch gets name of an operation as argument (instead of a function), and executes that operation according to a internal library of functions.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. What is the actual problem?

Comment: Judging by the source, `Q.makePromise.prototype.funcName = …`.

Comment: Still sounds like `Q.makePromise.prototype` would work.

Comment: @NasserTorabzade If you can give a reproducible example, I could help more. But Q has something called `Q.get`. Without knowing much about the problem, I think that would be the best I can offer

Comment: @minitech it does work. `Q.makePromise.prototype.after = Q.makePromise.prototype.then;` makes an alias `after` for `then`. OP did you try this?

Comment: @laggingreflex I tried that, didn't work. may you post  your test script?

Comment: @minitech it does work, thanks. I wasn't writing it correctly until laggingreflex posted their answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Q.makePromise` is the main Promise function that you want to extend. As mentioned by @minitech in the comments, and can be seen in the [source](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/v1/q.js#L767)

To make an alias, say "`after`", of `then` all you have to do is this:

```
Q.makePromise.prototype.after = Q.makePromise.prototype.then;
```

Then you can use `.after` instead of `.then`

```
defer = Q.defer();
defer.resolve(1);
defer.promise.after(console.log);
//=> 1
```

> I need an alias for .then() witch gets name of an operation as argument (instead of a function), and executes that operation according to a internal library of functions.

This creates a `.do` function which takes a string and displays it along with the value after promise has been resolved.

```
Q.makePromise.prototype.do = function(operation){
    return this.then(function(value){
        console.log('Do', operation, 'with', value);
    });
};
```

Then you can do

```
defer = Q.defer();
defer.resolve(1);
defer.promise.do('myoperation');
//=> Do myoperation with 1
```